# Tree with no child and no parent using d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to create a .json file with free nodes i.e. no child no parent associated with it. Suppose I have tree with nodes interlinked given by .json file
[image: Tree with no free nodes]

```
{

"name": "Max",
"value" : 100,
"children": [
{
    "name": "Sylvia",
    "value" : 75,
    "children":[
    {"name": "Craig", "value" : 25},
    {"name": "Robin", "value" : 25},
    {"name": "Anna", "value" : 25}
    ]
},
{
 "name": "David",
 "value" : 75,
 "children": [
 {"name": "Jeff", "value" : 25},
 {"name": "Buffy", "value" : 25}
 ]
},
{
"name": "Mr X",
"value" : 75
}
   ]
}
```

I want something like this

[image: Tree with free node]

How can I update the .json file to get the above tree with a free node using D3.js?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working example is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avrXXY) and I guess the code is similar.

I add a root node with a tag **"hidden": true**, and the nodes Brad and Max are on the same level.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "hidden": true,
  "children": [{
    "name": "Brad",
    "value": 100
  }, {
    "name": "Max",
    "value": 100,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Sylvia",
      "value": 75,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Craig",
        "value": 25
      }, {
        "name": "Robin",
        "value": 25
      }, {
        "name": "Anna",
        "value": 25
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "David",
      "value": 75,
      "children": [{
        "name": "Jeff",
        "value": 25
      }, {
        "name": "Buffy",
        "value": 25
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Mr X",
      "value": 75
    }]
  }]
}
```

for hide root node:

```
nodeUpdate.select("circle")
.attr("r", 6)
.style("fill", function(d) {
  return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
}).attr("class", function(d) {
  return d.hidden ? "hidden" : "";
});
```

and the diagonals weren't created:

```
// Transition links to their new position.
link.transition()
.duration(duration)
.attr("d", function(d) {
  return "hidden" in d.source ? null : diagonal(d);
});
```